# How to access hard disks in GNOME?

Tags: files

I have just installed 11.10 with GNOME. Now it seems I cannot access my secondary hard disks anymore. Is there a way to access non-system hard disk in GNOME?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Nautilus there is a possibility that

1. You have side panel disabled -> hit F9
2. You have side panel set to tree -> change it to places in the menu View>Sidebar>Places

Places will show you all drives. However on my system when I run Nautilus as sudo then I cannot see all drives apart from file system